# Constantly log into console using python3 cmd module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cmd

I'm trying to make something like server using python's CMD module for interaction, but I cannot find any information about printing logs into console on-the-fly without command "printLogs"
The good example of interaction with server is steamCMD.
Is there any way to do this using python's CMD module?

Screenshot of steamCMD window:
[image: steamCMD]

Comment: Are you trying to make a functioning terminal with its dedicated commands ? Or are you trying to achieve another goal ?

Comment: @Artemis i'm trying to make a terminal for manipulating telegram bot. Terminal should be able to print logs without executing command "do_printLogs(self, arg)" i.e. print logs automatically without doing a mess in input line

Comment: You should do an event triggered when the bot would detect a new message, that would call by itself `do_printLogs(self, arg)`